# Insert a toggle switch value into DB via Ajax - MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have CheckBox which is working like Toggle Switches and by default it is set `Checked/ON` and when i `UnChecked/OFF` the CheckBox,it will pass the value (OFF) not problem , but when i Checked the Checkbox again it cant pass the value (ON).

Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance :)

Example With ScreenShots:

[By Default it is set Checked/ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hRXN.png)

[Now I UnChecked/OFF , its pass the Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhrNs.png)

[Now i Checked/ON again, it cant pass the Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bwDN.png)

View:

```
 <tbody>
@foreach (var rma in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
         <label class="switch switch-text switch-primary switch-pill">
           <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
           <span data-on="ON" data-off="OFF" class="switch-label"></span>
           <span data-id="@rma.Id" class="switch-handle"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
   </tr>
  }
 </tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.switch-handle').click(function () {
        var Id = $(this).data('id');
        var checkStatus = this.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateNtf", "Account")',
            data: {
                id: Id,
                status: checkStatus
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {  
                if (result) {
                    console.log("Ok");
                } else {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult UpdateNtf(int? id, string status)
{
    var result = db.RMA_History.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.NTFOnOFF = status;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is being posted when the data is sent over to the method endpoint? I've had a problem similar to this, and it turns out when I check the checkbox the data is `True` and not `true`. Right now I'm looking at that code that did that and what I did was something like this: `usr.NotifyOrderActivity = (user.NotifyOrderActivity == "True") ? "Y" : "N";`. Perhaps you are having a similar quirk.

Comment: I've found out it was because Span element is always sending OFF :)